# Nodemailer - save png image from buffer to file on disk

Tags: node.js, image, buffer

I'm fetching received emails and it's attachments and I want to store it's .png image attachments to local storage.

There is my attachment object immediately after fetching:

```
{ contentType: 'image/png',
       fileName: '1,10.png',
       contentDisposition: 'inline',
       transferEncoding: 'base64',
       contentId: 'ii_jmykpyn60',
       generatedFileName: '1,10.png',
       checksum: 'b3f3de7de2ba946ff23ba2e41df87fae',
       length: 7942,
       content:
        <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 02 66 00 00
 01 cc 08 02 00 00 00 f0 21 f3 c8 00 00 00 01 73 52 47 42 00 ae ce 1c e9 00 00 00
 04 ... > }
```

Also when I'm sending it by POST request as "picture" the content is changed to:

```
picture:
    { type: 'Buffer',
         data:
          [ 137,
            80,
            78,
            71,
            13,
            10,
            26,
      ... 7842 more items ] }
```

Code I'm trying to get my image is:

```
    var decims = req.body.picture.data.join(" ")

    const buf = Buffer.from(decims);

    fs.writeFile('image.png', buf, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err) {
      console.log('File created');
    });
```

image.png appering in my folder but it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the Buffer to base64 and then save file.

```js
const bufferArray = req.body.picture.data;
  
const base64Image = btoa(
    bufferArray.reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
);
  
fs.writeFile(
  path.join(__dirname, 'image.png'), 
  base64Image, 
  { encoding: 'base64' }, 
  function(err){
    console.log('File Created');
  }
);
```

P.S: Make sure the file extension ".png" you use is the same with uploaded file extension.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be better to save png using the toBuffer function .

> The following works for me:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var Canvas = require("canvas");

var canvas = new Canvas(200, 200, "png");
var g = canvas.getContext("2d");
g.fillStyle = "black";
g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

var buf = canvas.toBuffer();
fs.writeFileSync("test.png", buf);
```